# Do people who experience heautoscopy become unable to see their reflected image in a mirror?

Tags: neuroscience, vision, consciousness, brain, hallucinations

I understand that people who experience **[autoscopy](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16571536/)** can see their body image outside them without a mirror. I had read many years back in a paper that people who experience the inverse phenomenon called **"heautoscopy"** become unable to see their body image in a mirror. I am not able to trace that paper. It is correct? Is there any place I can read more about it?

Answer (score 3):

While acknowledging the fact that Google delivers personalized results, I am fairly sure a Google search for "heautoscopy" will deliver you bucket loads of papers to read - I have copied a random handful for your convenience below under 'further reading'.

However, a popular source seems to contradict your definition, as it states [heautoscopy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heautoscopy) as being:

> A hallucination in which one sees one's own body from a distance.
> Heautoscopy may occur as a symptom in schizophrenia and epilepsy.

Your own referenced [Brugger (2002)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16571536/) paper gives a nice definition of both terms in one go:

> In an **autoscopic hallucination** the *observer's perspective is clearly body-centred, and the visual image of one's own body appears as a mirror reversal*. **Heautoscopy** (i.e., the encounter with an alter ego or doppelgänger), is defined as a *reduplication not only of bodily appearance, but also of aspects of one's psychological self*.

Not being able to see ones own reflection in a mirror would be an entirely different phenomenon, more akin to [mirrored-self misidentification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirrored-self_misidentification)

<sub>**Further reading**

**-** [Blanke & Mohr, *Brain Res Brain Res Rev* (2005); **50**(1): 184-99](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16019077/)

**-** [Brugger, *Cogn Neuropsychiatry* (2002); **7**(3): 179-94](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16571536/)

**-** [Brugger *et al*., *J Neurol Neurosurg Psychiatry* (1994); **57**(7): 838–39](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1073027/)</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much Alice for clarity! I am rewarding you a bounty of 100 points  :-)

Comment: @SijuGeorge No worries and the prospect of a bonus sounds really nice :) Thanks!